# install ros on odroid c2 running Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ros, ubuntu-xenial, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,
I'm trying to install ROS Kinetic on ODROID C2 running Ubuntu 16.04 but am facing some errors while running the rosdep command. I also tried the source installation but no luck! The wiki page I followed - [http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Source]
I had problems with the qtbase5 dependency installation. So, I tried installing QT5 separately but that too didn't work. I want to install MAVROS on ODROID C2. So, any help on this would be really appreciated. Tried looking at all the wiki pages possible but couldn't find a solution. Saw others also facing the same problem!

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240324/install-ros-on-odroid-c2-running-ubuntu-16.04/) by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-07-25**:
Which step gave which error? Could you post the specific messages?

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-07-25**:
Have you seen this: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/UbuntuARM
I'm not sure Kinect is there yet. See http://answers.ros.org/question/187472/ros-on-odroid-u3/ and perhaps http://answers.ros.org/question/235258/kinetic-desktop-full-for-ubuntu-armhf. I'm a noob and not ARM-user--good luck.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-07-25**:
Thanks for the info. I followed to steps to install ROS Indigo for Debian and somehow it worked! Thank you so much for the links..

**Comment by [neuronet](https://answers.ros.org/users/27484/neuronet/) on 2016-07-26**:
That's good, and it's supported through 2019..I would suggest, whatever you did (even if it is to just follow the instructions at that link) that you turn it into an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the instructions to install ROS Indigo for Debian and it worked fine on the ODROID C2 [Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial]
[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian)

But finally I wanted to install mavros on it and could not complete that one! So, if anyone has done it or has any idea please help me out!
Thanks

---

Originally posted by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) with karma: 46 on 2016-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-08-07**:
Did you ever get mavros working?  I need to get a C2 setup with mavros if it's possible.  Using Ubuntu 16.04 with Indigo seems like it could cause a lot of issues, so I haven't tried yet.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-08-10**:
Yes indeed! I installed ROS Kinetic and then got the MAVROS working on the C2 with some twitches in the installation.

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-08-11**:
How did you install Kinetic?  I tried a couple of methods and kept running into dependency issues.  If you get a chance, can you please post a solution?  Thanks.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-08-12**:
Yea, if you directly follow the steps you get dependency issues. So, for that I removed a package mali-X11, installed qt5-default and then installed ROS. After that, I reinstalled mali-X11 and was able to run roscore. [Detailed steps](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4lNqhhSk7SQZnBFNnkzRFEyRG8)

**Comment by [Sam94](https://answers.ros.org/users/27117/sam94/) on 2016-08-31**:
Thanks, I got it installed about a week ago.  As a quick addendum, this has to be done on a fresh installation of Ubuntu, if you try it after using 'apt-get dist-upgrade' you won't be able to access the necessary packages.

**Comment by [audia8.sid](https://answers.ros.org/users/27291/audia8.sid/) on 2016-09-01**:
OK great! Thanks for the info and cool you got it working.